# React-Router is not display anything and also no error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am try to make inventory list app with react and redux , but I have a small problem with need some understanding about it .

I know we have few way to create react components and try to get as much as possible all information , but still not sure why this issue is happen .

I have app.js which is my all React-Router set there

```
console.log('The application has been start...');

import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { IndexPage } from './modules/IndexPage'
import { AddItemForm } from './modules/ui/AddItemForm'
import { PageNotFound } from './modules/PageNotFound'
import { Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router'
import routes from './routes'

window.React = React

render(
   <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path='/' component={IndexPage}/>
        <Route path='/add' component={AddItemForm}/>
        <Route path='*' component={PageNotFound}/>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('react-container')
)
```

for IndexPage and PageNotFound the router display and render correctly , But for add , is display blank page with no error .

```
import { PropTypes } from 'react'

const AddItemForm = ({ onNewItem=f=>f, router}) => {
//const AddItemForm = () => {
    let _itemName

    const submit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        onNewItem({
            itemName: _itemName.value,
            itemCount: 1
        })

        router.push('/')
        _itemName.value = ''
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={submit} >something
            <label htmlFor="item-name"> Name Item</label>
            <input id="item-name" type="text" ref={(input) => _itemName = input } />     
            <button>Add Item</button>
        </form>
    )
}
AddItemForm.propTypes = {
    onNewItem: PropTypes.func,
    router: PropTypes.object
}

export default AddItemForm
```

in order to make sure there is something wrong with React-Router or the components which I made I change the AddItemForm with below code

```
 export const AddItemForm = () =>
    <div>
        <h1>Oops ! - The page is working!</h1>
    </div>
```

which start working normally which shows something wrong with my components but I am not able to understand what is the main issue. Please give me hit or point where is the issue or what is the different ?

Here is link of github for full source of application so far

[https://github.com/msc/Inventory-List](https://github.com/mavaj/Inventory-List)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce this issue. What I figured out is that you also need to import `React` for your component along with `PropTypes`.

So try importing `React`

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
```

in your `AddItemForm` component. Then worked for me.

Comment: This might be it. Every class that is using `jsx` needs to have `React` imported (even if you use nothing else from `React` itself).